# Best way to store GPS latitude and longitude with nodejs and database

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, gps, database

I would like to know what is the best way to store information about the GPS position of the device in real time using NodeJS and some database server.

**Example:**

Currently there are 5,000 devices connected to the server, each of these devices is sending information about their GPS position with a maximum timeout of 1 seconds.

Approximately per minute the NodeJS server will be receiving 300,000 PUT requests.

> Too much request, I know it.

Another important factor to take into consideration is that the database server is technically another server or instance.

> By the way, I plan to use Amazon AWS or Microsoft Azure as a cloud server provider.

So my question is, what is the most efficient way to store this information on realtime?

Among my options are MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, etc.
They could explain why it is better to use the option you recommend.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would say - MongoDB.

why i would say that -

MongoDB offers a number of indexes and query mechanisms to handle geospatial information. You can easily Store your location data as GeoJSON objects with this coordinate-axis order: longitude, latitude.
MongoDB also recently included support for additional GeoJSON types: MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, GeometryCollection.

MongoDB also offers a  vast set of query operators that allows you to easily query over the geospatial data such as:

```
$geoWithin
$geoIntersects 
$near
```

a typical example would be

```
{
   location: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [40.7829, 73.9654]
   },
   name: "Central Park, New York City"
}
```

You can go over a wide range of examples at https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/

Lastly, MongoDB let you build a 2D indexes on the geospatial data. looking at the usage you mentioned. it should come handy.

Comment: Thanks, I like you answer!

Answer (score 1):

As already say **MongoDB** has exactly all the needed in one place.
For the Index side, you can also consider "Partial Index" in order to exclude document that you don't need anymore (take in consideration all the Document less then 12 months only, for example): https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-partial/

For the Cloud side, i strong suggest you MongoDB **ATLAS**.
https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/pricing